# Convert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to only Y-m-d

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a column named "timestamp" in my DB with datatype `timestamp` and standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

When I echo it (`echo $row['timestamp'];`) i get this:

```
2016-01-18 21:06:37 
2016-01-19 12:32:16 
2016-01-19 20:52:41
```

But I want it to turn out like this:

```
2016-01-18
2016-01-19
2016-01-19
```

How should I do that? `Strftime` or something?

Comment: the number of posts on changing date format has reached such a critical mass they form their own black hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr:

```
substr($row['timestamp'],0,10)
```

This will output the first 10 characters of your string.

Answer (score 1):

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $row['timestamp'])));

Comment: `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in *path to file* on line 30 1970-01-01`. Thanks for trying the help me out though! :)

Comment: it looks like the - in the format causes an issue, try this:  echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $row['timestamp'])));